# Can I mount (a copy of) /dev as read-only

Tags: udev, read-only

#### TL;DR:

*I would like a mirror of /dev such as /dev_ro that is explicitly read-only; any time I become root and mess up a command, or any time I need to inspect raw devices but not write to them, as long as I use `/dev_ro/sda` and not `/dev/sda` I am protected from any accidents*

### I am wondering if there is any smart way of mounting an instance of devtmpfs as read-only

(I am on arch as I type so I am not sure if Ubuntu uses devtmpfs specifically, but I usually boot Ubuntu-based systems so am asking here first) such that I could have a set of device files for my system that would mirror those in /dev, but would be explicitly read-only.

Reading from device files is usually a super-user job in any linux-based system, because, for example, allowing unproveliged users to read in a disk and create an image to inspect later on a personal machine would circumvent the permissions system in the filesystem. Therefore we often want to run any applications reading from disk as root.

However, once we have become root, it becomes very easy to make a mistake and overwrite a disk, delete a partition, or any number of other Bad Things :TM:, because once we've become root, we have all power available to us, *even if we didn't need or intend to use it*.

I would like to have a read-only devtmpfs (or equivalent, see above) mounted such that I could safely minimise the number of times I might make an error as administrator, especially w.r.t. typos and other specialities more common at 4AM, so that I could access disks as root but prevent any writing to them for commands where this is not necessary.

For example, I am currently writing a script to make as full a backup as possible of my disks' MBRs or GPTs, to run before I do any partitioning work so I have a fallback every time. In this case, I explicitly don't want to write anything to the disk at any point in the script, but as on a default setup I would need to become root in order to read the disks, if there is any error in my script (not that unlikely) then I could potentially destroy my disk rather than backing up the partition tables as intended, because most commands that do the work are needing to be run with sudo.

If I could run `sudo sfdisk --dump /dev_ro/sda`  for example then this would circumvent the risk that if I have given sfdisk some bad options, such as `sudo sfdisk --delete /dev_ro/sda #WHOOPS!` it wouldn't physically be able to write to /dev_ro/sda when it came to it.

I would happily have a solution as simple as creating a tree of symbolic links, were it not for the fact that links can't have their own permissions and instead redirect to the original file.

## Options I have tried and potential alternatives

- using a read-only bind mount

  - This makes the filesystem read-only, but the files in them are not

    - `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev_ro/null` succeeds
- mount devtmpfs with the ro option

  - as above
- mount devtmpfs with the mode=440 option

  - Inspecting the mtab, this option seems to have been ignored, I am not sure where the relevant documentation is. Result seems to be same as above
- add my user to the group owning the device files (`disk` on arch) - this exposes a vulnerability if illicit user managed to become me, and does not work if I need to run a command as sudo in general, for example `sudo dd if=/dev_ro/sda of=/dev/sdb` for cloning a disk
- writing a C program that opens the device as read-only and forwards all requests to the device

  - Seems like a lot of risky work
- using flock to manage read and write locks

  - I don't know if this has any potential, I have not used them before. The filesystem could be mounted as above and we automatically call flock on all files inside to obtain a read lock. Subsequent programs would have to be wrapped to acquire the lock also, and this this might prevent them from writing to the device. Could cause issues when a disk is removed if it refuses to unlock.
- EDIT: New option, use a udev rule triggered for all devices. From the documentation I see that it is possible to set the mode of the created device file, or to add symlinks, but not anything at the moment that would create another device file. However it would be possible to run the `mknod` command and create a read-only device file in the ro folder, using the major/minor numbers. With preliminary tests this seems to work but I am reluctant without any confirmation that this would be okay to do.

Would anyone be able to suggest any ways I could achieve this and have a mirror image of /dev mounted somewhere in the filesystem, containing all of my device files, except with the caveat that thay are all available as read-only?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I suggest you use your first solution and don't mind much about that dd command

Comment: you do know you can do `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` to rebuild /dev?